# Oracle database: how to select all but return certain columns first?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

## Background

I have an oracle database table with a lot of columns that I'm running some queries on.

I don't know exactly what data I'm looking for in my query, so I want to return all columns, but I don't want to hunt and peck for columns I know are meaningful.

## Question

Supposing a table (Table 1) with *Column A, Column B, Column C....Column Z* --

Is there a way to essentially say "Select Column C, Column J, Column F, Column Q, and then the rest of the columns From Table 1" ?

## Things I've Tried

Keeping with pseudo-sql, Running:

> Select Column C, Column J, Column F, Table1.* from Table1

Doesn't help, because even though I don't mind the duplicates, oracle sees them as ambiguously defined columns and thus returns an error.

Comment: Also note -- I've tried the related answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596841/oracle-db-simple-select-where-column-order-matters but nothing there that I can see has panned out so far.

Comment: Why don't just enumerate columns in desired order explicitly (`SELECT C, J, F, A, B, D, ..., Z`)?

Comment: No it doesnt work like that... U have to select all the columns in ur desired order or do SELECT *

Comment: Could you provide an actual example?  I don't see anything in your query to cause difficulty for the database.  If you are joining tables together without aliasing columns, then I could see something about an ambiguous column definnition... Are you getting an error?  Please post it!

Comment: @Venk Nope, you can do both. Selecting some columns then using `*`

Comment: @Luc How to do it can u provide some example..

Comment: @Venk See answers of GolezTrol and Justin Cave.

Comment: @Luc Golez example is returning duplicates... but I want distinct list of columns in my SELECT query without hard coding them....

Comment: @VictorSorokin, the point was that I have a lot of columns and didn't want to have to enumerate each one (it's a temporary query).

Comment: @Gabe, the theorical example was enough to get me the answer I needed. An actual example would have just confused it. The issue was that by enumering columns and then adding on table.*, it produces ambiguous columns, unless I alias the ones I'm selecting first (GolezTrol's answer).

Comment: if you are using toad, hit f4 and order column name as you want, copy all of them with ctrl+c and then paste them, arrange them as you wish and just add select at the top, easy!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no nice and easy way to do this, other than specifying each column.

But if you don't mind the duplicates *and* you don't care about the column names, you could alias those columns:

```
Select 
  ColumnC as ColumnC1, 
  ColumnJ as ColumnJ1, 
  ColumnF as ColumnF1,
  t.* 
from 
  Table1 as t
```

Just for demonstration, I aliased Table1 as well. You may omit the `as` keyword, but I feel it makes it a little more readable.

Do note that while these extra columns are not at all difficult for Oracle to query, they do generate extra traffic. For testing, this solution is fine, but in production code, I would opt to only select the columns you need, and only select them once. It's only a little extra work. After all, how many columns do you have? :)

Comment: You can't use this technic if you don't alias your table.

Comment: Yes you can. Why do you think you can't?

Comment: I've just tested it on a 10G database. Is it a parameter somewhere that permits that ? Are you on 11G ? I get `ORA-00936: missing expression` and it points just before the star into `select project_id, * from pa_projects_all ;`

Comment: I think you mean you cannot use `*` by itself. You can however put the table name itself before it (`select Table1 X as X2, Table1.* from Table1`), so you don't need the table alias. You're right that you need to specify the table one way or another if you're going to use the asterisk, but this wasn't really the question. OP already uses this in the code sample in the question.

Comment: Oh! The table name is like a super alias :-)   Yes I meant you can't use the `*` alone.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of it this way, but I didn't mind aliasing the columns I was selecting (duh) and thinking about it from the other angle (aliasing my first few columns rather than the others) solved the problem I was facing. Much appreciated! And Golez, this is only for a test query; normally I'd absolutely list every column.

Comment: This doesn't work in Oracle 12C, Works fine without as keyword. So instead of using "Table1 as t" you should just use "Table1 t"

Answer (score 5):

You can work around the problem, however, by aliasing the columns that you are specifically selecting.  For example

```
SELECT columnC new_columnC, columnJ new_columnJ, columnF new_columnF, t.*
  FROM table1 t
```

to ensure that there are no identically named columns.