# SQL - Create table from Select + user defined columns and values

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Currently I have the following SELECT statement:

```
CREATE TABLE  TEST AS
SELECT ROW_ID,
            PROM_INTEG_ID,
            INTEGRATION_ID,
            BILL_ACCNT_ID,
            SERV_ACCT_ID,
            CFG_STATE_CD   
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE PROD_ID = 'TestProduct'
AND STATUS_CD = 'Active';
```

However I have to add some additional columns which do not exist in the PRODUCTS table and define them with my own name .e.g HIERARCHY

I tried using the WITH operand in my SQL query but it keeps failing as the syntax is wrong.

```
    CREATE TABLE  TEST AS
SELECT ROW_ID,
            PROM_INTEG_ID,
            INTEGRATION_ID,
            BILL_ACCNT_ID,
            SERV_ACCT_ID,
            CFG_STATE_CD   
            WITH
                  PRODUCT_HEIRARCHY varchar2(30)  'Test123Value'
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PROD_ID = 'TestProduct'
AND STATUS_CD = 'Active';
```

So in summary, I want to pull in columns from an existing table as well as defining some of my own.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the columns to the select:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS 
    SELECT ROW_ID, PROM_INTEG_ID, INTEGRATION_ID, BILL_ACCNT_ID, SERV_ACCT_ID, CFG_STATE_CD,
           CAST('Test123Value' AS VARCHAR2(30)) as PRODUCT_HIERARCHY
    FROM PRODUCTS
    WHERE PROD_ID = 'TestProduct' AND STATUS_CD = 'Active';
```

Note that the `cast()` is not necessary.  But it is a good idea if you want the column to have a specific type.

Comment: Thanks for this, out of curiosity is the WITH operator for multiple table SELECTS?

Comment: What if we want all columns from the original table ? `SELECT *, CAST('Test123Value' AS VARCHAR2(30)) as PRODUCT_HIERARCHY` does not seem to work (`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`)

Comment: Answer (I am new to oracle database) - we can't use the `*` alone we need the table name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727018/oracle-database-how-to-select-all-but-return-certain-columns-first#comment12368262_9727126

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D . . . You would qualify the `*`:  `products.*`.

Answer (score 2):

Also using `CTE` i.e. `WITH clause` as known commonly, you could `create table`.

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS 
WITH data AS ( 
   SELECT...
) 
SELECT * 
FROM data
```

Comment: Could you spell the query so it answers the question ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D The OP has not posted the details of the rest of the columns and tables he want to add to the select. So, I assume he has to JOIN the other tables and refer them in the column list using the table alias. All that will go inside the WITH clause here.

Comment: Cf. the answer by @Gordon